# Windows 8.1 is not activated even I have key in BIOS

Tags: windows-8, license-key

I have updated to Windows 8.1 few days ago. Everything was perfect and working great. Before that I was using (pre-installed) Win 8 Single Lang.

Now it is not activating even when I type the key from BIOS.

What should I do?

[image: screenshot of Activation dialog]

Comment: You updated to `Windows 8.1 Single Language` right?

Comment: Yes but after update it was running and was activated and now don't know what happened it is showing as not activated

Comment: Have you tried to activate it by phone?  You should have no problem activating Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8 SL license.

Comment: Did you mean by running slui 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found exact cause :
the Software Protection service was stopped

solution is :
To start the service sppsvc in delayed start up mode

Tried Regedit method from [Here](http://computerstepbystep.com/software_protection_service.html)

Now it is working after two restarts